# Maximum sum path in two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve a question from geeksforgeeks-
http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/max-sum-path-in-two-arrays/1

Given two arrays, the task is to find the maximum sum path from begining of any array to end of any array. We can switch from one array to another only at common points.

Let the two arrays be A and B with sizes M and N.

A path starts from begining of any array (A or B) and ends at any array(A or B).
Path continues in the right direction of the current array for non common points and we can switch the array only at common points. So at the these common points, we have two directions to follow.

e.g.

Array A is 2, 3, 7, 10, 12.
Array B is 1, 5, 7, 8.

We can go from. 
2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 10 -> 12.
Or. 
2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 8.
we can also start from. 
1 -> 5 -> 7 -> 8.
Or. 
1 -> 5 -> 7 -> 10 ->12.

While looking for the solution, I found the solution at:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-path-across-two-arrays/

I have done some investigations of my own and I believe that the solution is incorrect. It will fail in case of multiple common points in the array.

Please help me understand the solution if the solution is correct or give me a working solution.

My understanding: I think that if we try to understand it in terms of graph, this is a problem of finding max path in a DAG. And if I am not wrong, we can devise a dynamic programming formulation of it. I am unable to do the formulation.

Edit: My understanding is that it will fail in case we have duplicate common points. For example.
A: 2, 3, 6, 6, 8, 10, 13, 14.
B: 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14

Comment: "I believe that the solution is incorrect" - you could just test it, you know. There is actual code in 3 language and they even have a link to an IDE where you can just run it. What output do you think it right for your example? What output does it give?

Comment: DAG? won't there be a cycle for every equal pair?

Comment: I think it wouldbe a DAG because we are allowed to go from left to right

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is alright.

First, lets assume there are no multiple duplicate points. Two arrays have k points in common. So, the algorithm divides both array in k+1 distinct parts along common points. For example,5 and 10 is common in following arrays:

```
a = [0,2,5,7,10,11]
b = [1,3,5,6,10,12]
```

So,arrays are broken into 3 parts:

a becomes `[0,2],[7],[11]`

b becomes `[1,3],[6],[12]`

It then chooses the bigger segment of two for all k+1 parts( Here [1,3] is chosen from b. [7] from a and [12] from b ) and adds them all to result.(res = 4+7+12=23)

It then simply adds all common points to the final result.(res = 23+5+10 = 38)

This algorithm solves duplicacy problem by simply merging duplicate values from both arrays together. So if there three '5's in both arrays instead of one, it would simply consider a single 15 there in both arrays. If there were three '5's in a but two in b, it would handle them the same way as [10,5] and [10], last '5' in a is thus NOT considered a common point.

Comment: Sorry for the poor format of my question. I was referring to the input where there are three 5 in first array and second array has one. So there are three ways I can jump from first array to second